# Error when building an app with Gradle - No signature of method: build_49q3y83g7hdxe5s51k5187z33.publishing()

Tags: java, gradle, nexus

I'm following a tutorial on publishing artifacts to Nexus and a simple Java app is used as an example. A Gradle file is provided and meant to be changed. In the end, it looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifacts("build/libs/my-app-$version"+".jar") {
                extension = 'jar'
            }
        }   
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name'nexus'
            url "http://someip:someport/repository/maven-snapshots/"
            credentials {
                username project.repoUser
                password project.repoPassword
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '5.2'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I when I use the command `./gradle build` I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/matteo/Desktop/devops_bootcamp/java-app/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-app'.
> No signature of method: build_49q3y83g7hdxe5s51k5187z33.publishing() is applicable for argument types: (build_49q3y83g7hdxe5s51k5187z33$_run_closure1) values: [build_49q3y83g7hdxe5s51k5187z33$_run_closure1@79692f52]
```

Gradle version: Gradle 7.4.2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "no signature of method" problem is a bug that happens when a closure can't compile. It should be [fixed](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/20604) in the upcoming Gradle version 7.5.

The reason that it can't compile is because `artifacts` is a property and `extension` is a method (you have them both the other way around). There is also a method called `artifact` (in singular) that you probably want to use.

It is difficult to just guess what syntax to use, so check the documentation on it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html).

There are various ways you can express this publication, but one is like the snippet below.

```groovy
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        artifact("build/libs/my-app-$version"+".jar") {
            extension('jar')
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It now works, thank you! What do you mean by "you have them both the other way around"?

Comment: Just that when you write `artifacts(...)`, it is a method call. But that thing is actually a property intended to be used like `artifacts = ...`, and similar that `extension = ...` is used as a property, but should have been a method call `extension(...)`. It's not always clear when to use what unfortunately. It could also be that the tutorial you are following was correct for an older version of Gradle, but that they changed it in newer versions.